# Is it possible to state in one place that all outbound jms messages should have certain outbound property?

Tags: mule

I would like my outbound jms messages (either to queues or topics) to contain certain outbound property. Is it possible to state that in one place (say, for example, at the connector level)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to to this, you'll have to:

- Extend `org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage` and make it add the desired properties to the JMS Message that it creates,
- Register this custom transformer as the new default outbound transformer for the considered JMS connector:

  ```
  <jms:connector name="jmsConnector">
      <service-overrides outboundTransformer="apackage.IpAddingObjectToJMSMessage"/>
  </jms:connector>
  ```

Here is the code for the custom transformer:

```
package apackage;

import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.jms.Message;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.config.i18n.MessageFactory;
import org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage;

public class IpAddingObjectToJMSMessage extends ObjectToJMSMessage
{
    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(final MuleMessage message, final String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException
    {
        final Message jmsMessage = (Message) super.transformMessage(message, outputEncoding);

        try
        {
            jmsMessage.setStringProperty("IP", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            throw new TransformerException(
                MessageFactory.createStaticMessage("Failed to add IP address to JMS message"), e);
        }

        return jmsMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose all I want is to add a property as in `<add-message-property key="IP" value="#[function:ip]" />`. Could you provide a little example of how to configure the connector to do that? Am I required to write Java class to achieve that? If so, how to pass data to the transformer object? Many thanks

Comment: Did you read the answer? I've provided an example of how to configure the connector to do that. Extending `ObjectToJMSMessage` implies writing a Java class. You do not need pass data to the transformer object, it's done for you. Just override `transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)` to add `IP` to the newly created JMS Message.

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks. (I actually ended up modifying the Mule message prior to calling the base class method, as opposed to modifying the JMS message.)

Comment: +1 Good answer. Clean, concise, easy to incorporate into our project. Thanks!